# java mysql select function always returns 0

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, select

code:

```
public int getLastGotKill()
{
    Connection con = null;
    int last_pvp_time = 0;
    try
    {
        con = L2DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection(false);
        PreparedStatement statement;
        statement = con.prepareStatement("select last_got_kill from characters where obj_Id=?");
        statement.setInt(1, getObjectId());

        ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rset.next())
        {
            last_pvp_time = rset.getInt("last_got_kill");
            _log.info("last pvp time is : " + last_pvp_time);
        }
        rset.close();
        rset = null;
        statement.close();
        statement = null;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(Config.ENABLE_ALL_EXCEPTIONS)
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseUtil.close(con);
        con = null;
    }
    return last_pvp_time;
}
```

so when i call this function it gets into the `while loop` inside the `try{}` but when i try to print the value of the selected column it prints 0 and so it returns 0...

`last_got_kill` `column` in characters table is a `bigint(20)` type

i can see that there is a number in that column ex. 4294967295 which are

But why do i always get 0 back?

Comment: 4294967295 in hex is 0xffffffff which is -1 is two's complement. It's also larger than the largest value that can be stored in a signed int. It looks like you've messed up your data when inserting it.

Comment: If the query returns no rows, then your method will return 0, are you sure your query is actually selecting a row?

Comment: @MarkByers i simply store a date in milliseconds and want to get it back

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it returns rows because i can see the _log.info() message in the console, just returns 0 as well

Comment: @fxuser: You can't store number of milliseconds since the epoch in an `int`. The number is too big. You probably you mangled the data pretty badly when you inserted it by using a type that was too small. You may have to start from a clean copy of the data and reinsert it all. If you have no backup it may be gone for good, unfortunately.

Comment: You probably have an Exception being thrown, but since you chose to ignore them instead of letting them propagate as they should, you're returning an incorrect default value instead. Don't catch Exception. Don't catch anything that you can properly handle. Returning 0 instead of what has been asked is not properly handling an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to get a long instead . as your number exceeds int range.

`Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2147483647` which is surely less than 4294967295 
`Long.MAX_VALUE however is 9223372036854775807` seems to suit your case.

```
   long last_pvp_time = rset.getLong("last_got_kill");
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

4294967295 is too big to fit in an int. Try with a long: `rset.getLong("last_got_kill")`